# Filtering rows with Char based scientific notation in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that looks like this:

[image]

Let's call it `mutable`

And the structure looks like this:

[image]

What I want to do is to filter the rows in that table based on `evalue` columns
that contain info like '1e-31'. How can I do that with SQL query?

I tried this but no avail:

```
      SELECT DISTINCT query_id, subject_id, perc_idd, evalue
      FROM mytable
      WHERE evalue < 1e-4
```

Answer (score 0):

IN TSQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT query_id, subject_id, perc_idd, evalue
FROM mytable
WHERE Cast(evalue as real) < 1e-4
```

Comment: @Deepshika: that won't do. I want to get value less than equal than 1e-4.

Comment: @Deepshika: I got this error `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'real) as money) as nvarchar(255)),'.00','') < 1e-4' at line 1`

Comment: oh wrong tag then i suggested for T-SQL.. let me edit the same for mysql as well..

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
select * from table1 where SUBSTRING_INDEX(evalue, '-', 1)='le' and 
convert(SUBSTRING_INDEX(evalue, '-',-1), UNSIGNED INTEGER) < 4
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert it to binary and match

```
select id from test where CONVERT(id,BINARY) < CONVERT('1-e4',BINARY)
```